# How to change list item background color when selected in react native?

Tags: react-native, jsx, listitem, native-base

I'm using `native-base` ui kit. I'm trying to change the background color of selected items in sidebar. But how to do that? I've made changes to this  `theme/variablesplatform.js` file.

```
listBg: "#008080",
  listBorderColor: "#c9c9c9",
  listDividerBg: "#f4f4f4",
  listBtnUnderlayColor: "#008080",
  listItemPadding: platform === "ios" ? 10 : 12,
  listNoteColor: "#808080",
  listNoteSize: 13,
```

But can't see any changes. Please help me to find any solution? This is how the `ListItem` within sidebar looks like

```
  <List
            dataArray={datas}
            renderRow={data =>
              <ListItem
                button
                noBorder
                onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate(data.route)}
              >
                <Left>
                <Image
                  source={data.icon }
                  style={{width:30,height:30}}
                />
                  <Text style={styles.text}>
                    {data.name}
                  </Text>
                </Left>
                {data.types &&
                  <Right style={{ flex: 1 }}>
                    <Badge
                      style={{
                        borderRadius: 3,
                        height: 25,
                        width: 72,
                        backgroundColor: data.bg
                      }}
                    >
                      <Text
                        style={styles.badgeText}
                      >{`${data.types} Types`}</Text>
                    </Badge>
                  </Right>}
              </ListItem>}
          />
```

Please help me.

Comment: I was reading the docs and I think you need to use the `StyleProvider` component of `native-base` and provide the custom styles there. https://docs.nativebase.io/Customize.html

Answer (score 0):

you can change the background color when state change, triggered by (for example onPress).
but first you need include the color to your state, then change the state color whenever the list is pressed .

```js
//add color to your data
const lists = [{
    id: 1,
    nama: 'asep',
    cat: 'BAN',
    color: '#fff'
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    nama: 'deni',
    cat: 'BAN',
    color: '#fff'
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    nama: 'dini',
    cat: 'BAN',
    color: '#fff'
  },
];

// set your state
const [state, setState] = useState(lists);

// create handle change and pass id of item to it
const handleChangeColor = id => {
  let newState = state.map(item => {
    if (item.id === id) {
      // console.log(item.id + ' ' + id);
      item.color = '#eee';
      console.log(item)
    }
    return item;
  });
  setState(newState);
};

// render your list
{
  state.map(item => {
    return ( <
      List style = {
        [styles.listStyle, {
          backgroundColor: item.color
        }]
      }
      key = {
        item.id
      } >
      <
      ListItem thumbnail onPress = {
        () => {
          handleChangeColor(item.id);
        }
      } >
      <
      Body >
      <
      Text > {
        item.nama
      } < /Text> <
      Text note numberOfLines = {
        1
      } > {
        item.id
      } <
      /Text> <
      /Body> <
      Right >
      <
      Text > {
        item.cat
      } < /Text> <
      /Right> <
      /ListItem> <
      /List>
    );
  })
}
```